Second derivative from dataset or graph
I have a graph obtained from the eigenvalues of a matrix. I want the second derivative of each line (there are 3 independent curves in the graph) in specific ranges. Could you please help me?
One way might be to extract the data points and do the second derivative. I know how to extract the data points. How can I get the second derivative of the data points as well?
I appreciate your help.

look at ND. see how-can-i-differentiate-numerically

Assuming that you have the equidistant data points: d[[i]], the second derivative d2[[i]]== (d[[i-1]]-2d[[i]]+d[[i+1]])/dx^2 where dx is the distance between data points.
